# How do you subtract an arrays elements from a value while iterating through each element?

Tags: java

I need to create a program that is needs to find out which loans can be granted. I have a balance of 500 to start and an array of loan requests and it's done on a first come, first served basis. The problem I'm running into is it not updating my savings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```java
public class Exercise2 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int savings = 500;
        int[] loanAmount = {60, 20, 100, 80, 40, 300, 200, 100};
        int balance;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < loanAmount.length; i++) {

            balance = savings - loanAmount[i];
        
            System.out.println("Cash in the pot: " + balance + "\n" + "Loan amount requested: " + loanAmount[i] + " - " + " Loan amount granted!");
            System.out.println("Cash remaining in the pot: " + balance);
            

            if(loanAmount[i] > balance)
            {
             System.out.println("Cash in the pot: " + balance + "\n" + "Loan amount requested: " + loanAmount[i] + "\n" + "The exact loan request amount cannot be processed in full (insufficent funds available)." + "\n" + "However, we will give you what we can... " + balance);
            
            }
            
            if(balance == 0)
            {
            System.out.println("The following loan requests could not be facilitated" + "\n" + loanAmount[i] + "\n" + loanAmount[i]);
                
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Why can't `savings` be an integer initialized to 500 and just use `savings` instead of `savings[i]`?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you could find your answer with the error that your program gives you. Here is a tip : Why is savings an array ?

Comment: For that matter, why is `savings` a variable?

Comment: I originally had that but kept running into errors while trying to subtract the array elements.

Comment: I think balance and savings are the same thing for you. Or my english skills are bad.

Comment: i just changed savings back and I am no longer getting the error but its not keeping the balance the same after subtraction eg. for the first one would be 500 - 60 = 440 then on the next line it starts from 500 again.

Comment: Don't make `savings` an array. If you do, at least don't access it with the same index than a larger array, because when you increment it beyond the size of one of the arrays (but still within the size of the other), you'll cause an exception. In your case `savings[i]` could always be `savings[0]`because the savings array has only one value. Also, why are `balance` and `savings` separate? If you don't change the value of `savings`, of course it's always going to start at 500.

Comment: @JackMchugh you do realise you never change your value `savings` ? You only use it to substract.

Comment: Might you want to get rid of `balance` and change the line `balance = savings - loanAmount[i];` to `savings = savings - loanAmount[i];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
    package arraysAndStrings;

public class Exercise2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int savings = 500;
        int[] loanAmount = { 60, 20, 100, 80, 40, 300, 200, 100 };
        // int balance = savings;

        for (int i = 0; i < loanAmount.length; i++) {
            if ((savings - loanAmount[i]) >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Cash in the pot: " + savings + "\n"
                        + "Loan amount requested: " + loanAmount[i] + " - "
                        + " Loan amount granted!");
                savings -= loanAmount[i];
                System.out.println("Cash remaining in the pot: " + savings);
                System.out.println();
            } else if (savings > 0) {
                System.out
                        .println("Cash in the pot: "
                                + savings
                                + "\n"
                                + "Loan amount requested: "
                                + loanAmount[i]
                                + "\n"
                                + "The exact loan request amount cannot be processed in full (insufficent funds available)."
                                + "\n"
                                + "However, we will give you what we can... "
                                + savings);
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.println("No cash left!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is variables you don't need in there.

Comment: Removed extra variable.